# Spring Boot ignores spring.config.name/location properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I've got quite a simple `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  config:
    name: android,ios,test,web
```

[image]

I expected to gain an ability to name config files like `android.yml` and put them into

```
classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/
```

as the `DEFAULT_SEARCH_LOCATIONS` constant from the `ConfigFileApplicationListener` class specifies. I created a file in the same directory with the main config:

```
android:
  clientId: 0
  clientSecret: clientSecret
```

[image]

Then I wrote a `@Configuration` class with one method to get an instance of `ClientDetails` by the `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```
@Configuration
public class TrustedClientInformationConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = ANDROID)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ANDROID)
    public ClientDetails getAndroidClientDetails() {
        return new BaseClientDetails();
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, after autowiring, I got the instance with unfilled fields. What have I missed?

EDIT1: I found and debugged a method where `CONFIG_NAME_PROPERTY = "spring.config.name"` is used (it's only one usage), the `containsProperty` condition always returns `false`:

```
private Set<String> getSearchNames() {
    if (this.environment.containsProperty(CONFIG_NAME_PROPERTY)) {
        return asResolvedSet(this.environment.getProperty(CONFIG_NAME_PROPERTY),
                null);
    }
    return asResolvedSet(ConfigFileApplicationListener.this.names, DEFAULT_NAMES);
}
```

EDIT2: It is a try to create an oauth2 client configuration by moving properties to a separate file for each trusted client. They should be always instantiated despite the active profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spring.config` properties should be set on the command-line as they're needed before any config files are loaded.

However it looks like the feature you actually want is [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). They're a much easier way to organise different configuration for different environments. Files can be named `application-android`, `application-test`, etc.

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)